# How do I check for typos in a user submitted domain name?

Tags: python, spell-checking, email-validation, spelling

Basically, I'm trying to automatically correct user submitted emails with typos that are only a few letters off. For instance, if a user accidentally submits gamil.com or gmial.com instead of gmail.com, I would like to correct it. **What's a good method for handling this task?**

Comment: Does your application has a html-based frontend? I would suggest [mailcheck.js](https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck) then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pymailcheck:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymailcheck/1.0.0 or https://github.com/dbarlett/pymailcheck

You can use it to check the email-addresses entered by users and suggest the correctly written email-address.